# Image next to Block text

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, menu, block

Have a look at the menu link "Produkter" on http://marckmann.se/
I would like to add an arrow image in the right side of the drop down menu on some of the items. But since the text is styled into Blocks, it wont allow me.
Is there some way i could fix this?

Thanks :)!

Comment: You can use `list-style-type` , but it will come at left side. Maybe there is some way to show at right side. I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your CSS, for the `#dropdown div a` rule, add the flowing:

```
background: url('http://www.phillipsdepury.com/imgs/nav/arrow_small_left.gif') no-repeat right center;}
padding-right: 20px;
```

Replace your own arrow image. Also replace the 20px with the (width of your image + 5)px ...

Comment: Thanks a lot Night2!
I thought the right center option, only showed the right center of the image. Like when using sprites at menus!
I shouldve tested it though before asking. But you definetly confirmed it :) thanks

Comment: @Mathias You are welcome, I see you added the arrow now, you can add a few pixels of transparent space into right of your arrow image to avoid it from sticking to the exact right border for more beautiful looking ...

Comment: Yea Night, i did that just now :) Thanks!